# Can emails not actually sent by me appear in my "sent" folder?

Tags: email, email-spoofing

I have an outlook account (was hotmail).

I see some suspicious emails in my sent folder, to unkown both in the Thunderbird client and in the Outlook web client, which I did not send.

I already changed my password, worrying that it could have been compromised; however after inspecting the source I see that my address never appears: the sender is not actually me. Also, there is no "**To:**"

This makes me think that maybe the account wasn't compromised, but how comes that i see the emails in the sent folder?

**UPDATE**: while in one case there is no **"To:"**, the client shows "**unknow**" in the To column, and my address never appears in the mail source, there is also onother case where my address appears in the "**To:**" (not in the "**From:**"). I'd say that this other case looked like regular spoofing if the email was in the *Inbox* folder, but it is in the *Sent*

I include the email source (outlook website does not seem to have an option to copy only the headers). I changed ip addresses to unsignificant chars like xx.xxx.xx.xx, replaced malicious links and mail addresses. My address nor those of any contacts of mine seem involved. I may have forgotten something, feel free to edit out and please ask for more details if needed

```
Received: from VE1EUR02HT166.eop-EUR02.prod.protection.outlook.com
 (ffff:ffff:fff::ff) by AM4PR0401MB1970.eurprd04.prod.outlook.com with HTTPS
 via AM3PR04CA0148.EURPRD04.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM; Tue, 5 Dec 2017 16:25:07 +0000
Received: from VE1EUR02FT031.eop-EUR02.prod.protection.outlook.com
 (xx.xxx.xx.xx) by VE1EUR02HT166.eop-EUR02.prod.protection.outlook.com
 (yy.yyy.yy.yyy) with Microsoft SMTP Server (version=TLS1_2,
 cipher=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384_P384) id zz.zz.zzz.z; Tue, 5 Dec
 2017 16:25:07 +0000
Authentication-Results: spf=none (sender IP is kk.kk.k.kkk) smtp.helo=;
 hotmail.com; dkim=pass (signature was verified)
 header.d=oo.ATTACKER.NET;hotmail.com; dmarc=permerror action=none
 header.from=oo.ATTACKER.NET;
Received-SPF: None (protection.outlook.com:  does not designate permitted
 sender hosts)
Received: from SNT004-MC5F5.hotmail.com (hh.hhh.hh.hh) by
 VE1EUR02FT031.mail.protection.outlook.com (jj.jjj.jj.jjj) with Microsoft SMTP
 Server (version=TLS1_2, cipher=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384_P384) id
 15.20.282.5 via Frontend Transport; Tue, 5 Dec 2017 16:25:06 +0000
X-IncomingTopHeaderMarker: OriginalChecksum:255C39763F036EA23876BAB41428C4FF25DFCEDF36BCA46234B50E8284D7EA26;UpperCasedChecksum:07DB12FEFEE63D3A0397067AECD2CCE92B37535297A742DC2CBAC5E1A3F32423;SizeAsReceived:1422;Count:15
Received: from oo.ATTACKER.NET ([kk.kk.k.kkk]) by SNT004-MC5F5.hotmail.com with Microsoft SMTPSVC(7.5.7601.23143);
     Tue, 5 Dec 2017 08:25:05 -0800
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha1; c=relaxed/relaxed; s=selector1; d=oo.movingright.net;
 h=From:Sender:List-Unsubscribe:Subject:Content-Type:Reply-To; i=noreply@oo.ATTACKER.NET;
 bh=gxYz3JpgRC3azGshKXDTANqNEhw=;
 b=1ciZCIO2c4qmrODX8SGMiTuGiS2luC5RKM47rWBLQUybeNQgnFjMuONYKnXhQOPTNQP+SzLsieTM
   hlYByyHUVnN5M1xIe4lVkh8ZlDYwM1tHxCZy7m0YenYRY+4YlPSKDYnjipdTA5F2bC+rJ39pCWwp
   q/3t2Wx7un+6GX+btcg=
DomainKey-Signature: a=rsa-sha1; c=nofws; q=dns; s=selector1; d=oo.movingright.net;
 b=stTfJpnCQ75QjWEEG63JZ9XcPnXW6zsghQgf2LYTgo19PBNoeJ6efXiP2QZzEbwZFaS7B2tOLY8x
   B++5EP1ewy8zbXldZ53IBCRSl6LOEcqXeRsORkgy+BInb7bHy52yFdLBOjtZb21WVPvgC9TDz98p
   IjFh3DjV57fuqVDoH2c=;
From: â¡â¡ Sarah â¡â¡ <qvc@ATTACKER.NET>
Sender: " yh" <noreply@ATTACKER.NET>
List-Unsubscribe: <8ZVtjLfkbt85tdeRBs@tac3.betaparkarc.com>
Subject: â¡â¤ Can't wait anymore ... See my nude pics and let's meet â¤â¡
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
 boundary="----=_NextPart_6B34F3F8_4354_464B_B214_CE288821B8D1"
BCC:
Reply-To: <contact@ATTACKER.NET>
Return-Path: <>
Message-ID: <SNT004-MC5F5Gr0ePGO003ebae1@SNT004-MC5F5.hotmail.com>
X-OriginalArrivalTime: 05 Dec 2017 16:25:05.0149 (UTC) FILETIME=[9BBA42D0:01D36DE5]
Date: Tue, 5 Dec 2017 08:25:05 -0800
X-IncomingHeaderCount: 15
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-Network-Message-Id: b28d5a5a-a945-46a9-cf2f-08d53bfcbf47
X-EOPAttributedMessage: 0
X-EOPTenantAttributedMessage: 84df9e7f-e9f6-40af-b435-aaaaaaaaaaaa:0
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-MessageDirectionality: Incoming
CMM-sending-ip: kk.kk.k.kkk
CMM-Authentication-Results: hotmail.com; spf=pass (sender IP is kk.kk.k.kkk)
 smtp.helo=oo.movingright.net; dkim=pass header.d=oo.ATTACKER.NET;
 x-hmca=pass header.id=noreply@ATTACKER.NET
CMM-X-SID-PRA: noreply@ATTACKER.NET
CMM-X-AUTH-Result: PASS
CMM-X-SID-Result: PASS
CMM-X-Message-Delivery: Vj0xLjE7RD0yO0dEPTI7U0NMPTQ=
CMM-X-Message-Info: 3c21WZ1hAlvD6z4W+Uwvl9ImsHEUa/TV22P+NgFf/vRX9nK3L2uwOHntIsd8XhO4MbD/28XyRlUbWcA5rYswXa+72BTBwB5Sjk+MpOUeyPiAEw/KxFOjtzAqRDMnx/llO2pTeGfmjbRpokFCOA+AJ0EO+i1WEUDFXkKB2G4i4OvYAYxvsh7k/g==
X-MS-UserLastLogonTime: 12/5/2017 3:11:17 PM
X-Microsoft-Exchange-Diagnostics: 1;VE1EUR02FT031;1:kb26mkc2Gur4wkI3JkriHM1wTddL9iWWcHF8PPFz5TcFeFV6caw5/jYRkE6/8tct2iUEH2xxCvRz535hWmL6hwGjt6VSnp1kCzmmqB0JsktK2UGIE8duDKAnu4QUQF2j
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthSource: VE1EUR02FT031.eop-EUR02.prod.protection.outlook.com
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthAs: Anonymous
X-MS-PublicTrafficType: Email
X-MS-Office365-Filtering-Correlation-Id: b28d5a5a-a945-46a9-cf2f-08d53bfcbf47
X-Microsoft-Antispam: BCL:0;PCL:0;RULEID:(5001025)(4604075)(4605076)(8291501071);SRVR:VE1EUR02HT166;
X-Microsoft-Exchange-Diagnostics: 1;VE1EUR02HT166;3:4UNbiEkNL3mQWkzT67Va8hemwyLjtytaRUijT0qm/aoHOBYOXTQrCKkvtrg9rGotlmFLQ5QJFldCX9rn8dO5y+pxFceWJG3xxUSeYZIgMoCJUEH0I1uB5+X9P6bpHqFWzMAc3HJ++RJFivVDYJi7/193o6PA0uA9rCOt9s5uwnxO7NIvX/ZxMRqJeeeuSZcPwrDVzoJSlf7Pt1tMg5G/JBXr0X8uEirCN91QzB8TxVZCLuHaVfzVTWhTjDsFIPRM5+6euyaRYNUHpSjq2OwS5QP0GCT+4mp51afJzsUD+DJbH0+Rn44Ech1ZdIiKhAqZ;25:qcljjPzjH11Lj+HscQXGwwqNnt108wu/IHYd9ab632NZMC6tpH3GBYE5Hs1jg93yzuhJSl9Jf3Z0+s/vfqIYJmrF8/d6MSqP6Gatornju3nnIJZGg6tuQoYyjGFLDZUpjO0oL0nnC4Hs9Md85wYi8ab9J0Xf0GEZzl9ML1iNVOMxm1fGPJlE1Q6O2VMaf9/d/LoNMmf8o/7CHFtB/BjBimjpMhMTu2vuVtVk+QNYVPWwywcRCFNqsPTj7T71Rk0WNM8NgDEf+8dLt08P1AEemq8QUFwaH0rGr+xB7W7arJGF4Yy6Bh/8B36/Nz3DRsD7mI5/bIap28U5Zo0sG5pIMw==;31:uTCLahoMZ9sdLlG7MIxV2lDbtQeE9LENR88NYwRnQByI3+8yXyBPFS7sffHycpyPjSYTzLbn88/KCR2K0VSmZqlmvR9kGlj/qQcEaw6DqXQhbEm/vBmvmepG7gGbKmngRounJ5zBmXX+bcWYJwA9QnEF/rSJxsgNYdVscGdkPGntiTOlzQAD4vO0IPNzEDd9htBKPfam6uGqbuqReoZkkutaShrfIkw7n90YTCgxWEc=
X-MS-TrafficTypeDiagnostic: VE1EUR02HT166:
X-Exchange-Antispam-Report-CFA-Test: BCL:0;PCL:0;RULEID:(444000031);SRVR:VE1EUR02HT166;BCL:0;PCL:0;RULEID:(100000803101)(100110400095);SRVR:VE1EUR02HT166;
X-Microsoft-Exchange-Diagnostics: 1;VE1EUR02HT166;4:hDH6XB0xIALryjgDjwIOx2Mgbqxvg++40e05pYvaOGpUzJDLGfF2jNUvGo50BbVQj/1sZYoMuDB70naRENULw3CQOzJ7+V3OfranNp1mMKWg4XsTpNjQLO009/Bhv0/XutVJ0w+Y3ybKYgTvNE+g8d6kuCPPRv8tqwqfsIHf+5qYk7+AifrAQxFY62wFqj3mbsjCACwLJZ+8GRMDlWbmGLJCm6XRPniIvbrgFh//+N3OA4hJx2dbhIFeiUs8ZGiOOTo/2666Rier5D9be3RtRA==;23:fA6EZEu66lYNTqqQcD87MThbCfjplzYIdAynpuO9FmKhoqlHSEN3S73/hcxVRPz5I3w4058XT/daNKW0LsggBSogz5hykYGQnR8GBiSPnJZPrRAVaKQi6+SHXKiXmqB8mq9JkbH7xh80M6RUjlJYzEHXjxBQv3y/Xfnw/I7efy/D24MA1yG5uyxutDcypQ5XxczMDRF54CwoPzC3BnyUEA==;6:J2gFGwtvjTE+hWQZXPuZ4jAMV6++ojIqltBRPELV3zRSMKpfCY9zlcUxofex6By9d5MEZ6VhvHQoLS4IFAEo3apmbdJs0ljp3kPK7Aps/7TcPbbMRFfUQWSAL8+FG/hoWgyRIFm/LVBSXp0hsJy/bVn1NJhEbryNlJy2agXuHRHkF5OkEPE7nGnt0yH+Tzw1MfVINlS2/oUcYAFAVTR/Gbi5Ux3D4/7obnxo8oTmoiusfww65fRyeIlT/P4VWsTUuCKwHGoFxrgX2h8MQD4HUr/7rS+ZvP5JJtDzG3l51a0X3bDYbdsjrZM5es8TQhoI3AJPpTRsUbgzUbEmNCiRuTpDH4rlb6HE33bwCVcd4sg=
X-Forefront-Antispam-Report: SFV:NSPM;SFS:(98900018);DIR:INB;SFP:;SCL:1;SRVR:VE1EUR02HT166;H:SNT004-MC5F5.hotmail.com;FPR:;SPF:None;LANG:;
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-SCL: 1
X-Microsoft-Exchange-Diagnostics: 1;VE1EUR02HT166;5:nzTosku0e8yI5Od9hGVFDDpSDTaJjG8QrHpcUlBQ0pXoq6Y4R1LLBguzSJQ7DzonSL/7gFit2S8fnLJ5eHoqimUIKt97iu8tT+unYfE0+gk/odfRpO/B10yFS/I0I91ByhRuSUCsfB49iNdcILvT5Z5UjAhZf/375TIBF0rXt8A=;24:tmqDK7FyJfylF73xuv0hmvZ/d8CXBnwO3VR1OV30HXRz0ZKBL4qDnUYeYJ/kuVXPLTHe1uJpb6Fnoz0W3ozuqdn9osrQuAeu/CuJzPoG1do=;7:2laKC5VUl7zA1zWcpTVr93tYaLmh+stpopd5xb0jvca1ZN1PqNQyG7/GKMgbNeQXIT6EEWQU5jj9xS1LQdp+6Pp63aH6NkpHaT0Bf720xps+RtmUQbdxGkqP8ynAz+TekpX+4BEPKvxBjIcVbtIQbcdwjtsNWoXh4MqvldTy32TUlhOlDXm5ApuPHYxCDfib+FLNe01akYFzqt/Gda7O0u+xPo2KhT8UuLTmvhPPist+/rre8vdWRmc9ohHzBSQb
SpamDiagnosticOutput: 1:99
SpamDiagnosticMetadata: NSPM
X-OriginatorOrg: outlook.com
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-OriginalArrivalTime: 05 Dec 2017 16:25:06.0213
 (UTC)
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-Network-Message-Id: b28d5a5a-a945-46a9-cf2f-08d53bfcbf47
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-Id: 84df9e7f-e9f6-40af-b435-aaaaaaaaaaaa
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-FromEntityHeader: Internet
X-MS-Exchange-Transport-CrossTenantHeadersStamped: VE1EUR02HT166
X-MS-Exchange-Transport-EndToEndLatency: 00:00:01.3796011
X-MS-Exchange-Processed-By-BccFoldering: 15.20.0282.012
Importance: high
X-Priority: 1
X-Microsoft-Exchange-Diagnostics:
    1;AM4PR0401MB1970;27:OEPydiXdg1o82HkMUTG0XYX75zuvBxunKAUxDkItlxqYk+4MsCz14PBBHKu1DCh0Ai5orrSvfUSC2bbODcdo49227dYXiBpwoeSh2zGbVUhL5vpEhSm9Gm00Wc6L43Za
X-Microsoft-Antispam-Mailbox-Delivery:
    abwl:0;wl:0;pcwl:0;kl:0;iwl:0;dwl:0;dkl:0;rwl:0;ex:0;auth:1;dest:J;WIMS-SPF:oo%2emovingright%2enet;WIMS-DKIM:oo%2emovingright%2enet;WIMS-822:qvc%40oo%2emovingright%2enet;WIMS-PRA:noreply%40oo%2emovingright%2enet;WIMS-AUTH:PASS;ENG:(400001000128)(400125000095)(5062000261)(5061607266)(5061608174)(1002268)(4900095)(4921089)(3120004)(4950112)(4990090)(9140004);RF:JunkEmail;OFR:SpamFilterAuthJ;
X-Microsoft-Antispam-Message-Info:
    ZdW969Ez/4mHyEZtbSq5HOPAuVUD85rjbP8oC86qtJF/ZIJDSGmjQGwa4BVuxwWk+8aiKF2HYfg3cyTFIU79jY+Hnxc1VxRPT6QqeVm5CjLPzaYLD45M89dl8s7kQEMsD3LfzTI1puwVZjPfff2WWHX1aEbg/PyktaAGKCU5sWKVvl754LzJPh/cDkiQ8b5TNPrDZBfDG0nYuhUvylTq2Y6cXJ0klQGtKwD6bsLTrqJyF6OMsZlUSsrHriIY7VeAlHWruIEuKJyFBbbTR6Ue4/PeQ9QXhCmsGcK2QN+0MI2KNco4MTsBvXIB1DJOuSM/
MIME-Version: 1.0

------=_NextPart_6B34F3F8_4354_464B_B214_CE288821B8D1
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
 boundary="----=_NextPart_571E1FD8_86E7_4BD2_829A_B257F132850D"
X-Microsoft-Exchange-Diagnostics:
    1;AM4PR0401MB1970;27:OEPydiXdg1o82HkMUTG0XYX75zuvBxunKAUxDkItlxqYk+4MsCz14PBBHKu1DCh0Ai5orrSvfUSC2bbODcdo49227dYXiBpwoeSh2zGbVUhL5vpEhSm9Gm00Wc6L43Za
X-Microsoft-Antispam-Mailbox-Delivery:
    abwl:0;wl:0;pcwl:0;kl:0;iwl:0;dwl:0;dkl:0;rwl:0;ex:0;auth:1;dest:J;WIMS-SPF:oo%2emovingright%2enet;WIMS-DKIM:oo%2emovingright%2enet;WIMS-822:qvc%40oo%2emovingright%2enet;WIMS-PRA:noreply%40oo%2emovingright%2enet;WIMS-AUTH:PASS;ENG:(400001000128)(400125000095)(5062000261)(5061607266)(5061608174)(1002268)(4900095)(4921089)(3120004)(4950112)(4990090)(9140004);RF:JunkEmail;OFR:SpamFilterAuthJ;
X-Microsoft-Antispam-Message-Info:
    ZdW969Ez/4mHyEZtbSq5HOPAuVUD85rjbP8oC86qtJF/ZIJDSGmjQGwa4BVuxwWk+8aiKF2HYfg3cyTFIU79jY+Hnxc1VxRPT6QqeVm5CjLPzaYLD45M89dl8s7kQEMsD3LfzTI1puwVZjPfff2WWHX1aEbg/PyktaAGKCU5sWKVvl754LzJPh/cDkiQ8b5TNPrDZBfDG0nYuhUvylTq2Y6cXJ0klQGtKwD6bsLTrqJyF6OMsZlUSsrHriIY7VeAlHWruIEuKJyFBbbTR6Ue4/PeQ9QXhCmsGcK2QN+0MI2KNco4MTsBvXIB1DJOuSM/

------=_NextPart_571E1FD8_86E7_4BD2_829A_B257F132850D
Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"
X-Microsoft-Exchange-Diagnostics:
    1;AM4PR0401MB1970;27:OEPydiXdg1o82HkMUTG0XYX75zuvBxunKAUxDkItlxqYk+4MsCz14PBBHKu1DCh0Ai5orrSvfUSC2bbODcdo49227dYXiBpwoeSh2zGbVUhL5vpEhSm9Gm00Wc6L43Za
X-Microsoft-Antispam-Mailbox-Delivery:
    abwl:0;wl:0;pcwl:0;kl:0;iwl:0;dwl:0;dkl:0;rwl:0;ex:0;auth:1;dest:J;WIMS-SPF:oo%2emovingright%2enet;WIMS-DKIM:oo%2emovingright%2enet;WIMS-822:qvc%40oo%2emovingright%2enet;WIMS-PRA:noreply%40oo%2emovingright%2enet;WIMS-AUTH:PASS;ENG:(400001000128)(400125000095)(5062000261)(5061607266)(5061608174)(1002268)(4900095)(4921089)(3120004)(4950112)(4990090)(9140004);RF:JunkEmail;OFR:SpamFilterAuthJ;
X-Microsoft-Antispam-Message-Info:
    ZdW969Ez/4mHyEZtbSq5HOPAuVUD85rjbP8oC86qtJF/ZIJDSGmjQGwa4BVuxwWk+8aiKF2HYfg3cyTFIU79jY+Hnxc1VxRPT6QqeVm5CjLPzaYLD45M89dl8s7kQEMsD3LfzTI1puwVZjPfff2WWHX1aEbg/PyktaAGKCU5sWKVvl754LzJPh/cDkiQ8b5TNPrDZBfDG0nYuhUvylTq2Y6cXJ0klQGtKwD6bsLTrqJyF6OMsZlUSsrHriIY7VeAlHWruIEuKJyFBbbTR6Ue4/PeQ9QXhCmsGcK2QN+0MI2KNco4MTsBvXIB1DJOuSM/

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"><img src="MALICIOUS_URL_7" width="1" height="1">
<p style="text-align: center;">
<font face="Comic Sans MS">
<b>
<a href="MALICIOUS_URL_6">
<font color="#CC0066" size="6">Hi</font></a></b></font></p><p><center><p>
<center><font size="5" face="comic sans ms">
<a href="MALICIOUS_URL_5"><b>
<font color="#DF0101"><span style="background-color: #FFFFFF"><marquee> â©â¡â© i'm here to make you something special  â©â¡â©</marquee></span></font></b></a></center><br>
</font><a href="MALICIOUS_URL_4"><b>
<font size="5" face="MV Boli" color="#000000">
<span style="background-color: #FFFFFF; text-decoration:none">Well, I hope my new photos will melt even the coldest soul... ;)</span></font></b><p>
<span style="text-decoration: none">
<b>
<font color="#993333" size="6" face="IrisUPC"> &nbsp;</font><font size="7" color="#CC6699" face="IrisUPC">I want to hug you between my legs</font></b></span></p>
<font color="#DF0101" size="6">
</font>
<font color="#DF0101" size="6">
</font>
</b>
<b>
<span style="text-decoration: none">
<font color="#DF0101" size="6" face="Matura MT Script Capitals">
I'm wild and looking to hookup 
!</font></span></b></a><b><font color="#DF0101" size="6"><font size="5" face="comic sans ms" color="#000000"><a><br>
</font>
</font>
<a>
<font size="6">
<p></font>
<font size="5" face="Lucida Sans"><font size="6">â©â©â©â© CLICK HERE â©â©â©â©</font><font color="#DF0101" size="6"> </font> </font></b><font color="#DF0101" size="6"><font color="#DF0101" size="6"><font color="#DF0101" size="6" face="comic sans ms">
</p>
<p>
<center></font><font size="5" face="comic sans ms" color="#000000">
<font color="#DF0101" size="6"><a href="MALICIOUS_URL_3"><img src="MALICIOUS_URL_8"></a></center><br> 

<center><a href="MALICIOUS_URL_1"><img src="MALICIOUS_URL_9"></a></center><br> 

<center><a href="MALICIOUS_URL_2"><img src="MALICIOUS_URL_10"></a></center><br>








------=_NextPart_571E1FD8_86E7_4BD2_829A_B257F132850D--

------=_NextPart_6B34F3F8_4354_464B_B214_CE288821B8D1
Content-Type: text/plain
X-Microsoft-Exchange-Diagnostics:
    1;AM4PR0401MB1970;27:OEPydiXdg1o82HkMUTG0XYX75zuvBxunKAUxDkItlxqYk+4MsCz14PBBHKu1DCh0Ai5orrSvfUSC2bbODcdo49227dYXiBpwoeSh2zGbVUhL5vpEhSm9Gm00Wc6L43Za
X-Microsoft-Antispam-Mailbox-Delivery:
    abwl:0;wl:0;pcwl:0;kl:0;iwl:0;dwl:0;dkl:0;rwl:0;ex:0;auth:1;dest:J;WIMS-SPF:oo%2emovingright%2enet;WIMS-DKIM:oo%2emovingright%2enet;WIMS-822:qvc%40oo%2emovingright%2enet;WIMS-PRA:noreply%40oo%2emovingright%2enet;WIMS-AUTH:PASS;ENG:(400001000128)(400125000095)(5062000261)(5061607266)(5061608174)(1002268)(4900095)(4921089)(3120004)(4950112)(4990090)(9140004);RF:JunkEmail;OFR:SpamFilterAuthJ;
X-Microsoft-Antispam-Message-Info:
    ZdW969Ez/4mHyEZtbSq5HOPAuVUD85rjbP8oC86qtJF/ZIJDSGmjQGwa4BVuxwWk+8aiKF2HYfg3cyTFIU79jY+Hnxc1VxRPT6QqeVm5CjLPzaYLD45M89dl8s7kQEMsD3LfzTI1puwVZjPfff2WWHX1aEbg/PyktaAGKCU5sWKVvl754LzJPh/cDkiQ8b5TNPrDZBfDG0nYuhUvylTq2Y6cXJ0klQGtKwD6bsLTrqJyF6OMsZlUSsrHriIY7VeAlHWruIEuKJyFBbbTR6Ue4/PeQ9QXhCmsGcK2QN+0MI2KNco4MTsBvXIB1DJOuSM/




------=_NextPart_6B34F3F8_4354_464B_B214_CE288821B8D1
Content-Type: text/plain
X-Microsoft-Exchange-Diagnostics:
    1;AM4PR0401MB1970;27:OEPydiXdg1o82HkMUTG0XYX75zuvBxunKAUxDkItlxqYk+4MsCz14PBBHKu1DCh0Ai5orrSvfUSC2bbODcdo49227dYXiBpwoeSh2zGbVUhL5vpEhSm9Gm00Wc6L43Za
X-Microsoft-Antispam-Mailbox-Delivery:
    abwl:0;wl:0;pcwl:0;kl:0;iwl:0;dwl:0;dkl:0;rwl:0;ex:0;auth:1;dest:J;WIMS-SPF:oo%2emovingright%2enet;WIMS-DKIM:oo%2emovingright%2enet;WIMS-822:qvc%40oo%2emovingright%2enet;WIMS-PRA:noreply%40oo%2emovingright%2enet;WIMS-AUTH:PASS;ENG:(400001000128)(400125000095)(5062000261)(5061607266)(5061608174)(1002268)(4900095)(4921089)(3120004)(4950112)(4990090)(9140004);RF:JunkEmail;OFR:SpamFilterAuthJ;
X-Microsoft-Antispam-Message-Info:
    ZdW969Ez/4mHyEZtbSq5HOPAuVUD85rjbP8oC86qtJF/ZIJDSGmjQGwa4BVuxwWk+8aiKF2HYfg3cyTFIU79jY+Hnxc1VxRPT6QqeVm5CjLPzaYLD45M89dl8s7kQEMsD3LfzTI1puwVZjPfff2WWHX1aEbg/PyktaAGKCU5sWKVvl754LzJPh/cDkiQ8b5TNPrDZBfDG0nYuhUvylTq2Y6cXJ0klQGtKwD6bsLTrqJyF6OMsZlUSsrHriIY7VeAlHWruIEuKJyFBbbTR6Ue4/PeQ9QXhCmsGcK2QN+0MI2KNco4MTsBvXIB1DJOuSM/


------=_NextPart_6B34F3F8_4354_464B_B214_CE288821B8D1--
```

Comment: I'm no expert on email but I believe the email server can change what is in the sent folder.

Comment: @Qwertie can you explain what that would imply?

Comment: @thecarpy I will try to do so. No contacts of mine seem involved. Can I safely leave the addresses of the attackers? There are also ip addresses and other info that looks like better not exposing.

Comment: You should first try replace mail and IP addresses with non significant characters (xxx or yyy), using same sequence if same address appears multiple times in the mail.

Comment: Your account was probably compromised and an e-mail was sent. Good thing it wans't a mass spam.

Comment: @Overmind Do you know how they are able to remove my address from all headers? And whom was it sent, since there is no "TO" ?

Comment: The same script that stole your outlook password probably did that too. I'll explain it a little in an answer.

Answer (score 1):

2 mandatory steps to do is run anti-spyware and anti-malware and use outlook again only if you changed your password.

There are attachments and links currently in circulation under various forms that the first thing they do is to use scripts to read your outlook account password.

After obtaining that, they can do things like:

- Send sensitive information (info theft) towards other addresses which they hide
- Send spam - thousand or even more messages that you will never know they were sent until it's too late - you will know about it only when you will start to receive bounce-backs and/or your e-mail IP is blacklisted
- Send various type of SMTP attacks
- Spread the same content until there are enough drones for a larger attack

The problem with this type of attachments is that they seem very legit and they use standard e-mail functions so well defined and limited that they will not be detected as a thread by any anti-virus-like defensive system - no AV blocks legit outlook e-mails.

If your e-mail server is not secure and does not require authentication, then stealing the password is not necessary and the attacker will be able to send any e-mails he wants from any of your server's accounts.

The source fields can be faked just like the destination ones, so in order to see what actually went there you will have to investigate this on your e-mail server by looking at the logs in that times interval.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Imagine MS Outlook creates a file on your computer that stores your email history (for example .pst or .ost). The file gets edited every time you receive a message or delete a message or send a message. It is meant to be edited by certain rules, so that Outlook or another program can open it and display it in "folders" for your convenience. However, some other program with sufficient privileges might edit that file, creating a false record of sent messages, or deleting a true record.

It is also possible that a malicious program would send emails from your account, and not cover its tracks, and thus the sent emails appear completely accurately in your records, even though you personally did not send them.